# How can I average durations in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have timespans that originated in SQL that look like:

--Almost 2 seconds pass each time
`00:00:01.9277759`
`00:00:01.7708749`

I formatted the column with a custom number format:  `[hh]:mm:ss.0`

I tried to average the data:  `=AVERAGE(A1:A2)` or `=(A1+A2)/2`

Result:  `#DIV/0!` or `#VALUE!` (respectively)

How can I average durations in excel?

Comment: The second is working fine for me. Try trimming your values: `=(TRIM(A1)+TRIM(A2))/2`.

Comment: You need to first convert the data into true Excel time values.

Comment: @Jerry Using your formula I get a number.  `1.6088E-05` that's a really small number and I don't know what the measurement is in?  I expect something close to 1 second.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent how do I do that?

Comment: @P   See my Answer.......uses a "helper" column........approach only valid if your data is less than 10 seconds

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Just format that small number to `[hh]:mm:ss.0` (or any more convenient format to you).

Comment: With `[hh]:mm:ss.0` as my format I still get the same errors.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey You are applying that format to the result, right? I mean, on the `1.6088E-05`? Because otherwise, I don't understand how you can get an error on that one.

Comment: I am and I still get the error.  Maybe you have a different version of excel?  I don't think the trim is going to work anyways.  I need to apply this to ~220 rows.

Comment: I'm on excel 2010 but that should not be an issue, nor should the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in **A1** and **A2** , etc. In **B1** enter:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,9)
```

and copy down

Then:

=AVERAGE(B1:B2)  will display 1.8493254

Comment: I used `=--RIGHT(A1,10)` and hand edited the few values that went over a minute.